# Pairwise Distance calculation (multidimentional matrix) for features similarity

Tags: matlab, matrix, machine-learning, computer-vision, cluster-analysis

Ok here is the formula in matlab:

```
function D = dumDistance(X,Y)
n1 = size(X,2);
n2 = size(Y,2);
D = zeros(n1,n2);
for i = 1:n1
    for j = 1:n2
        D(i,j) = sum((X(:,i)-Y(:,j)).^2);
    end
end
```

Credits [here](http://statinfer.wordpress.com/2011/11/14/efficient-matlab-i-pairwise-distances/) (I know it's not a fast implementation but for the sake of the basic algorithm).

Now here is my understanding problem;

Say that we have a matrix `dictionary=140x100` words. And a matrix `page=140x40` words. Each column represents a word in the 140 dimensional space.

Now, if I use `dumDistance(page,dictionairy)` it will return a `40x100` matrix with the distances.

What I want to achieve, is to find how close is each word of `page` matrix to the `dictionary` matrix, in order to represent the page according to dictionary with a histogram let's say.

I know, that If I take the min(40x100), ill get a 1x100 matrix with locations of min values to represent my histogram.

What I really cant understand here, is this 40x100 matrix. What data does this matrix represents anyway? I cant visualize this in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor comment before I start:

You should really use `pdist2` instead.  This is much faster and you'll get the same results as `dumDistance`.  In other words, you would call it like this:

```
D = pdist2(page.', dictionary.');
```

You need to transpose `page` and `dictionary` as `pdist2` assumes that each **row** is an observation, while each column corresponds to a variable / feature.  Your data is structured such that each **column** is an observation.  This will return a `40 x 100` matrix like what you see in `dumDistance`.  However, `pdist2` **does not use `for` loops**.

---

Now onto your question:

`D(i,j)` represents the Euclidean **squared** distance between word `i` from your page and word `j` from your dictionary.  You have 40 words on your page and 100 words in your dictionary.  Each word is represented by a 140 dimensional feature vector, and so the rows of `D` index the words of `page` while the columns of `D` index the words of `dictionary`.

What I mean here in terms of "distance" is in terms of the feature space.  Each word from your page and dictionary are represented as a 140 length vector.  Each entry `(i,j)` of `D` takes the i<sup>th</sup> vector from `page` and the j<sup>th</sup> vector from `dictionary`, each of their corresponding components subtracted, squared, and then they are summed up.  This output is then stored into `D(i,j)`.  This gives you the dissimilarity between word `i` from your `page` and word `j` from your `dictionary` at `D(i,j)`.  The higher the value, the more **dissimilar** the two words are.

**Minor Note:** `pdist2` computes the Euclidean distance while `dumDistance` computes the Euclidean **squared** distance.  If you want to have the same thing as `dumDistance`, simply square every element in `D` from `pdist2`.  In other words, simply compute `D.^2`.

Hope this helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer I totally understood this now. But I have a another question that just came up. If we had a smaller dictionary than the page, for example dict=140x20 and page=140x50. Suppose that D=(50,1) =0. That means, that word 50 from page is similar to word 1 from dict. If I wanted to create a histogram of word occurrences of page in accordance to dictionary, should I include this value or not?

Comment: @TStsn. - I need some clarification.  What do you mean by "word occurrences of page in accordance to dictionary"?  Does this mean how many times a word from `page` occurs in `dictionary`?

Comment: Yes, I would say so.  What you can do is for each row of `D`, count how many times you encounter 0.  Let's say the first row had 3 zeroes.  This means that the first word from `page` appeared in the entire dictionary three times.  You can easily compute a histogram by doing:  `Dhist = sum(D == 0, 2);`.  This will then give you a 40 element histogram, where each element tells you how many times each word in `page` appears overall in `dictionary`.

Comment: The above will look for **exact** matches.  If you also want to include **very similar** matches, consider counting those words that are not only 0, but are also within a very small constant (i.e. 0.1 or so).  You would then change the code so that it's `Dhist = sum(D <= 0.1, 2);`. I don't know the dynamic range of these features, so 0.1 is simply a random guess.  You'll have to play around with this constant to get good results.